# Image with color representation of "Uncalibrated" does not appear on iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, color-profile

I have an image that appears on Windows and Android devices, but not an iPhone 13, in Chrome or Safari:

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/f92Em47.jpg"/>
```

Looking at the properties of the image, the "Color representation" property appears as "Uncalibrated":

[image]

What can I do to fix the color representation and ensure the image appears on all devices?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the image in paint.NET
2. Choose Image > Apply Embedded Color Profile

[image]

3. Save the image. The "Color representation" property should now be correct:

[image]

Although there is little known about this issue, it appears that the graphics hardware of certain phones is unable to render images that do not have a valid color profile. See below for some relevant posts:

https://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=178351
https://community.adobe.com/t5/lightroom-classic-discussions/colour-representation-uncalibrated/m-p/13012552